# Calculate the circulation of the vector field $ \vec A=\hat r r \sin (\phi)+\hat z z \cos (\phi)$

Tags: calculus

[image]

Calculate the circulation of the vector field $ \vec A=\hat r r \sin (\phi)+\hat z z \cos (\phi)$ around a wedge defined by $0 \leq r \leq 4$ , $ \ 30^{\circ} \leq \phi \leq 45^{\circ}$ . Assume the path of circulation is anti-clockwise around the wedge.

**Answer:**

I know that circulation is given by the formula

$\int_C V \cdot ds $

Let $ x=4 \cos \phi. \ y=4 \sin \phi, \ z=z $

position vector $s=<4 \cos \phi, 4 \sin \phi,z>$

$\therefore ds=<-4 \sin \phi, 4 \cos \phi,0>$

Thus,

$circulation=\int_C \vec A \cdot ds=\int_{30^{\circ}}^{45^{\circ}} <4 \cos \phi, 0,z \sin \phi> \cdot <-4 \sin \phi, 4 \cos \phi,0> d \phi$

Am I right?

Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two errors. One: in the circulation formula $ds$ should be written as $\vec{ds}$. It is a vector along the trajectory. On the circular part, it is always perpendicular to $\hat r$, so the dot product is $0$. The second mistake is that you forgot to integrate along the straight lines. On both those lines $\vec{ds}$ is either parallel or anti-parallel to $\hat r$. So you need to compute the integral from $r=0$ to $4$ when $\phi=30^{\circ}$ and add the integral from $4$ to $0$ when $\phi=45^{\circ}$.